# Why does my Vissless LP85 Bluetooth keyboard refuse to connect to my Windows 11 PC but works with others?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, windows-11-v22h2

I have two wonderfully clicky and loud Vissless LP85 keyboards.  Love them both to bits but one of them refuses to co-operate with my PC. It connects without any problems to other BT devices (I tested it with four other computers and an Android phone) and it worked fine.  It just refuses to communicate with my main workhorse PC.

I've tried the usual things, even turned off the built-in BT in the PC and tried an external dongle.  Nothing.  When trying to pair, the PC sometimes detects the keyboard and sometimes doesn't even detect it. If it detects the keyboard it tries to connect only to give up after a while with a communication error.

The PC connects without any problems and works flawlessly with the other keyboard and a bunch of other BT devices.

I've tried all the usual registry tricks, external PC Bluetooth dongle, threatening the PC, begging the PC, sacrificing small animals, etc. I'm out of ideas.  Any suggestions?